# Using aggregate and mutate to get mean of two columns (updated)

Tags: r

I have a dataframe, df:

```
df <- structure(list(unit = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("unit1", "unit2"), class = "factor"), 
    testnum = c("t1", "t1", "t1", "t2", "t2", "t1","t1", "t1", "t1", "t2"),
    length = c(3, 4, 2, 
    4, 4, 5, 
    3, 6, 7, 
    6), width = c(4, 5, 
    1, 1, 4, 6, 
    6, 7, 7, 
    7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
    df
    unit testnum length width
1  unit2      t1      3     4
2  unit2      t1      4     5
3  unit2      t1      2     1
4  unit1      t2      4     1
5  unit1      t2      4     4
6  unit2      t1      5     6
7  unit2      t1      3     6
8  unit2      t1      6     7
9  unit2      t1      7     7
10 unit1      t2      6     7
```

I want to take a mean of the length and width columns, and use it to summarise those two columns (and compress other columns that have the same value).  Essentially, I am trying to create the following:

```
df
   unit   test average_length    average_width 
1 unit1     t2       4.666667         4.000000
2 unit2     t1       4.285714         5.142857
```

I tried this, but get an error message:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(
    average_length = aggregate(length ~ unit, ., mean),
    average_width = aggregate(width ~ unit, ., mean)
)
Error: Column `average_length` is of unsupported class data.frame
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: df %>% group_by(unit, testnum) %>% summarise(average_length = mean(length), average_width = mean(width))   will this work for you?

Comment: Also, your expected output looks like you wanted aggregated data by group, but you are using mutate only in your code?